# Is multicycle MIPS always faster than single cycle?

Tags: architecture, mips, hardware, processor

When I calculated execution time for some instructions, the multicycle design time was longer than the single cycle. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, the amount of cycles per instruction for a single cycle implementation is simply 1. For a multicycle implementation, that cycles per instruction will always be greater than 1.

Remember that execution time can be calculated using the formula Execution Time = (CPI * Instruction Count) / (Clock Rate).

Assuming you are keeping the instruction count and clock rate the same when making your comparison, then yes a multicycle implementation will always be faster than a single cycle one.

However, it is probably important to mention that the clock rate between a single and multicycle implementation will not be the same in practice. In the single cycle, the clock rate will be limited by the instruction that takes the longest to execute, or the critical path delay of your processor design. The clock rate for the multicycle implementation on the other hand is not limited by the critical path delay, so a faster clock rate can be achieved.